# How to using Laravel passport middleware in ExpressJS route?

Tags: laravel, express

I have Laravel project using laravel passport api (localhost:8000), and I have project epxressjs (localhost:3000), how I can using Laravel passport to expressjs middleware. I think, I will call api laravel passport (localhost:8000) after each use route in expressjs (localhost:3000).

```
noteRouter.get('/:id', Should I call laravel passport api here ? ,  (req, res) => {
    NoteService.getDetail(req.params.id)
        .then(post => res.send({ success: true, data: post }))
        .catch(res.onError);
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to call the passport API?

Comment: Because I have a project that has been built for a long time, now I want to re-use that passport project. =))) Sorry, my english is a bit bad